# SwiftUI @Publish from inside closure not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have this Swift code below which I was using with Storyboards and now want to re-use with SwiftUI.  It uses GeoFire to query locations in Firestore within certain radius radiusInM, as per Firebase documentation.

I want to publish array 'locations' to a View which should show them on a map, but while the array gets populated with locations (with 'self.locations.append(location)') this does not result in this being Observed by the View.

What is the reason for this?  Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import FirebaseFirestore
import GeoFire

struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

class LocationsViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var locations: [Location] = []
    
    // location
    var lat: Double = 0.0
    var lng: Double = 0.0
    
    // firestore
    var db: Firestore!

    // Location records from Firestore
    var matchingDocs = [QueryDocumentSnapshot]()
    
    func getLocationsOnButton() {
        
        getLocations(completion: {
            print("*** finished all queries and getting locations ***")

            for i in self.matchingDocs {

                self.lat = i["lat"] as! Double
                self.lng = i["lng"] as! Double
                
                let location = Location(name: "Test", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.lng))

                self.locations.append(location)
            }
        })
    }

    func getLocations(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        let radiusInM: Double = 1000
        
        var queriesFinished = 0
        matchingDocs.removeAll()

        // Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
        // a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
        // depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
        let queryBounds = GFUtils.queryBounds(forLocation: center,
                                              withRadius: radiusInM)
        
        let queries = queryBounds.map { bound -> Query in
            return db.collection("places")
                .order(by: "geohash")
                .start(at: [bound.startValue])
                .end(at: [bound.endValue])
        }
        
        let numOfQueries = queries.count
        print("There are", numOfQueries, "queries")
        
        // Collect all the query results together into a single list
        func getDocumentsCompletion(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) -> () {
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("Unable to fetch snapshot data. \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            for document in documents {
                let lat = document.data()["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
                let lng = document.data()["lng"] as? Double ?? 0
                let coordinates = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                let centerPoint = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)

                // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash accuracy, but most will match
                let distance = GFUtils.distance(from: centerPoint, to: coordinates)
            
                if distance <= radiusInM {
                    print("appending ", document.documentID)
                    if !matchingDocs.contains(document) {
                        matchingDocs.append(document)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            queriesFinished += 1
            print("Finished query # ", queriesFinished)
            
            allDone()
        }
        
        // After all callbacks have executed, matchingDocs contains the result.
        for query in queries {
            print("Processing query")
            query.getDocuments(completion:getDocumentsCompletion)
        }
        
        func allDone() {
            if queriesFinished == numOfQueries {
                print("Completed all queries")
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the View

```
struct MapView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    @StateObject private var locationsViewModel = LocationsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: locationsViewModel.locations) { location in
            MapMarker(coordinate: location.coordinate)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

If I manually populate the locations array like this

```
    @Published var locations: [Location] = [
        Location(name: "Test", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.6541, longitude: -79.3780))
    ]
```

The marker is displayed properly on the Map.

This is the view that starts getting the locations from Firestore.

```
struct LocationView: View {
    
    let places = LocationsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        MapView()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
   
        Spacer()
    
        HStack(alignment: .center) {

            Button {
                places.getLocationsOnButton()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "location")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you're using this in your `View`

Comment: You never call your get locations function.

Comment: MapView is combined with another View which calls getLocationsOnButton().  I'll post it in a moment.

Comment: you'll have better luck removing the view model objects, in SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already and it diffs those structs to create/update/remove UIView objects automatically for you.

Comment: The comments here worked for me so I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LocationView`, you should have `@StateObject var places = LocationsViewModel()`.

In `MapView`, you should have `@ObservedObject var locationsViewModel: LocationsViewModel`, and pass the `LocationsViewModel` to it from `LocationView`, using: `MapView(locationsViewModel: places)`